# How to create a constant string in a perl mason file?

Tags: perl, mason

Simple question: Is there a way that I can create a constant string inside a perl mason file?  I want to be able to assign a hard coded string to a variable at the top of my perl file and then be able to use it throughout the rest of the file.  Something the equivalent of Java's

`private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "Bobby Joe";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent concept in Perl is the `constant` pragma:

```
% use constant DEFAULT_USERNAME => "Bobby Joe";
<h1>Welcome, <% DEFAULT_USERNAME %></h1>
```

This is syntactic sugar that actually creates a subroutine called `DEFAULT_USERNAME` in the current package, as if you said

```
sub DEFAULT_USERNAME () { "Bobby Joe" }
```

Comment: And where exactly in my mason file would I put the `% use` line? Do I need to enclose it in any tags?

Comment: A `use` statement can go anywhere in a mason file (a `.mc` file, right?). As I understand it, you can put Perl code on a line that begins with `% ` (don't forget the space), or inside `<%perl></%perl>` or `<%init></%init>` tags.

Comment: And what if I wanted this constant to be public (accessible to other files)? Would I have to change the use line? How would I access it from other files? Thanks

Comment: Then put it in a module that exports it (that's another small can of worms) and `use` the module in your template, or (in Mason) put it in a separate file and include it in other templates with the `<& constants.mi &>` syntax.